# Tomcat/9.0.53 on ubuntu 2204 error 516 I/O ERROR catalina.pid after reboot

Tags: apache2, tomcat

i succesfully installed on ubuntu 2204 an open source application for
Asset Management called CMDBuild (https://www.cmdbuild.org/en/homepage?set_language=en)

everything worked and the web application was running fine,

but after a reboot tomcat doesn’t start automatically anymore
so i tried to manually launch script startup.sh to start tomcat
and the last line of output is:

Using CATALINA_PID: /home/danesi/cmdbuild_30/bin/catalina.pid
./catalina.sh: 516: echo: echo: I/O error
Tomcat started.

now the webserver respond correctly (tomcat home page is showed)
but not the cmdbuil home (ipserverort/cmdbuild)
it respond HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

It seems that the user with which tomcat starts, does not have permissions to write to the file …/bin/catalina.pid.

anyone knows how can i handle this problem?

thanks in advance

Francesco